# Format timezone offsets that starts with + or -

Tags: php, string

How can I format a string to prepend `UTC` if it starts with `+` or `-` and add a `:` before the last two digits if it ends with 4 digits?

Examples and expected result:

```
PST > PST
+08 > UTC+08
-0845 > UTC-08:45
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "PST";
if (substr($string, 0, 1) === '+' || substr($string, 0, 1) === '-'){
        if(strlen($string) == 3){
        $newString = 'UTC'.$string;
    }
    else{
        $newString = 'UTC'. substr($string, 0, 3). ':' .substr($string, -2, 2);
    }
}
else{
    $newString = $string;
}

echo $newString;
```

You don't need regex for that or at least regex seems overkill. You can simple create this logic using an if-else and modify your string accordingly

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't check if it starts with - or + and will give "UTCPST" where it should be "PST". Thank you!

Comment: My first example was "PST > PST", eg. not "PST > UTCPST". I'll figure it out with if statements. Was just thinking a regexp would do it in a one liner. Thank you kind sir!!

Comment: Modified my answer, i thought PST was a label-title for some reason, my mistake.

Comment: No worries. That worked fantastic! Thank you again!

Comment: Glad i helped !!!